# Android Q (Api 29) Discover Bluetooth devices (with location disabled)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-10.0

I managed to scan / discover bluetooth devices on Android P and earlier without needing location services enabled. Any of these methods work for me:

- `BluetoothAdapter` scan methods using any of deprecated `LeScanCallback` or `ScanCallback` (*targeting API level 22 or earlier*)
- `BluetoothAdapter startDiscovery` listening to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND IntentFilter`

However, any of these fail on Android Q with the message.-

`E/BluetoothUtils: Permission denial: Location is off`

Since it's pretty self explanatory (and actually enabling location services on device make it work) I'm afraid now is mandatory having location services enabled to play around with Bluetooth capabilities, but just in case, **anyone knows of any other workaround to scan for Bluetooth devices without having location enabled?**

Comment: Check this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128901041

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhThorat. So, if I'm not wrong, this is a recognised bug and they're thinking of addressing it in a future release, is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Great, that's good to know :) Thank you so much @SaurabhThorat!

Comment: Actually, `Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)`, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128901041#comment6